# Persistent UI failed to open file - error in xcode osx

Tags: macos, cocoa, sqlite, persistent, savestate

How to solve the following error and why i'm getting this.
**Persistent UI failed to open file file://localhost/Users/ev_mac13/Library/Containers/com.xxxxx.testData/Data/Library/Saved%20Application%20State/com.xxxxx.testData.savedState/window_5.data: Too many open files (24)**

I m using sqlite database in my applicatation. This error appearing inbetween running the application.

**EDIT**: The data was fetched and used in collection view and array controller. If i got the above error then i cant open sqlite database.

**Assertion failure in -[SQLiteDBConnection executeQuery:], /Users/admin/Desktop/march14/feb22/ToolBox/ToolBoX/DBConnection/SQLiteDBConnection.m:186
2014-03-15 10:25:04.339 ToolBoX[2939:303] Error while creating add statement. 'unable to open database file'**

**EDIT #2:**

i just typed `lsof` in osx terminal, it shows too many sqlite connections and close all connections. Now fixed.

Comment: how many files can you have open at once? try `sysctl kern.maxfiles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this with permissions errors in my home folder.

However, if you're using a SQLite wrapper directly, it's possible it's leaking (as in memory leak) database/connection instances and/or not closing them properly when done, which means new connections are opened in addition each time the database is touched. Get familiar with Instruments (the "Leaks" instrument, specifically) if you're not already, then post the results if you're still stuck.

Comment: "permissions errors in my home folder" - how to detect and solve?

Comment: That's more a question for other StackExchange sites but the short of it is: Run Disk Utility, choose the volume, then run Repair Permissions.

Comment: still i getting the above error, even though i removed the code to fetching from the database.

Comment: i followed this link `http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/122202-cannot-load-interface-builder-file.html` . my data base file was listed 7000+ times in terminal.

Comment: thank you for your time man. Finally my problem got fixed. Too many sqlite connections was created. thats Why i got those problem. now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

can try in terminal:

```
xcode-select --rest
```